# How to use FluentValidation with Web Api 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I am trying to use [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) in a web api 2 project but I can't get the Model State to work. I downloaded [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.WebAPI/) and added this line to my Application_Start

```
      FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Then in my model I added

```
 [Validator(typeof(LotValidator))]
```

yet my ModelState.IsValid is always valid. I don't know what I am missing or if it the fact that I have my model in a different class project(though I do reference the [FluentValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/) package) then my webapi project.

Comment: You don't perchance have your validator classes as internal, do you?  I created some validator classes and left them as the VS default "class MyValidatorClass..." and forgot to make them public.  Since they were in a separate project and were internal by default they couldn't be instantiated by the web project and the validation just didn't execute...no errors either.

Answer (score 2):

You might not have added `ValidateModelStateFilter` to the filters.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Fluent Validation
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config);

        //snip..    
    }
}
```

I have a long post on how to do everything here - http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/12/fluent-validation-with-web-api-2/

Answer (score 0):

This is probrably some "Passing null object to API" question. If this is the case, you need to validate if your API is receiving some null argument.

[FluentValidation is designed to
validate the properties of an object](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/255#issuecomment-219822381)